# Flutter Plugins pub conflict when other dependency depends on it and it also still in developing

Tags: flutter, dart

Because I made some change in `Plugins/Path_Provider`, and it's still in development.

I know this is an **`expect result`** because of `version conflict` for `Path_Provider` with two version, one in `git` and one in `pub host`.

But still this is a case when development. Is there any **`best practice`** for this specific duration case ?

`pubspec.yml`:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  localstorage: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: #^1.1.0 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/plugins
      ref: dev/path_provider_add_getApplicationLibraryDirectory
      path: packages/path_provider
      version: ^1.1.0
```

Console after `flutter packages get`:

```
[MyApp] flutter packages get
Running "flutter pub get" in MyApp...                            
Because localstorage 2.0.0 depends on path_provider ^1.1.0 and
  no versions of localstorage match >2.0.0 <3.0.0, 
  localstorage ^2.0.0 requires path_provider from hosted.

So, because MyApp depends on both path_provider from git and
  localstorage ^2.0.0, version solving failed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dependency_overrides` in your pubspec.yml of course just for development. 
here is the [details](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides)

`pubspec.yml`:

```
dependencies:
  ...
  localstorage: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: ^1.1.0 

dependency_overrides:
  path_provider: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/plugins
      ref: dev/path_provider_add_getApplicationLibraryDirectory
      path: packages/path_provider
      version: ^1.1.0
```